# How to log in to MongoDB by CAS?

Tags: mongodb, cas

I have Mongodb and HDFS, and I want to log in to them by CAS( single sign on). Is this possible and, if so, how do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify. are you trying to log in or trying to log? Did you intend to use the `mangodb` tag rather than the `mongodb` one?

Comment: sorry, I spell error,I want to login to mongodb

Comment: No probs, Jelly, have made some minor changes to you question based on that info. Please review and make sure I haven't screwed things up royally :-)

Comment: it means I can login to mongodb and hdfs by CAS？